# WiFi network adapter suddenly disappeared

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, laptop

I have here a Medion Akoya S4220 notebook, without CD/DVD drive, without ethernet and everything integrated except the hard disk (now a SSD). First, the network adapter (WiFi) was hidden in device manager. After a system restore the network adapter isn't here anymore.

Now the only connection to the outside is USB. I tried to install the network driver (Realtek RTL8723B Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter). Therefore I took the driver from the recovery partition.

I tried different things (checked power settings, booted in safe mode, checked BIOS settings, ...), but the WiFi adapter doesn't exist according to Windows.

What can I do?

Comment: There is no physical wifi switch anywhere on the laptop.. is there? (or a combination of fn-key with one of the function key to turn on/off the wifi)

Comment: You said the hdd is now ssd. Did you take the laptop apart to change the hard drive or does it just slide in and out? If you had to disassemble the laptop it's possible you disconnected a ribbon cable.

Comment: @Darius: didn't found such a key. Imho it should appear in the Device Manager?

Comment: @CodyPace: There is an extra slot for that. Nevertheless, it was opened before (because of RAM upgrade), but it worked for four months now. The system is completely integrated, but this case is not completely excluded.

Comment: try going to medions website from a different computer and download the drivers on a flash drive from there

Comment: @CodyPace: On the Medion site there is no manual available (404), no software downloads ... I tried to install the drivers from the recovery partition, but that didn't help.

Comment: @testing I don't know specifically for medion but for some laptop that I've encountered, the physical switch would remove it off the device manager. And enabling it would suddenly bring the windows sound as if USB device has been plugged in, and it appears in device manager...

Comment: @Darius: Is there such an option in Windows 10 for that? There is no physical switch either.